# error while install libc6:amd64

Tags: 12.04

when I run this command
"sudo apt-get install libc6"
I got an error i.e.,
libc6:amd64 cannot be configured because libc6:i386 is in a different version

Comment: Make sure your system is up-to-date (`sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, no package "held back"). If your system is up to date and the problem persists, paste the full, exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try with :

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-amd64 libc6
```